# Issue connecting to hdfs using cloud shell

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-platform, hortonworks-data-platform, cloudera-cdh, google-cloud-dataproc

I find it quite hard accessing my hadoop data file system using google cloud shell (**I’ve created a cluster on the Google Cloud Platform just to learn**).

The generic **‘hdfs dfs -ls**’ or ‘**hadoop fs -ls gs://**‘ doesn’t seem to work and I’ve been doing quite a but of trial-errors to figure out how. 
Can anyone help me out on this? 
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cloud Storage connector](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage) which provides an implementation of the FileSystem abstraction, and is available in different HDP versions, to facilitate access to GCS, and then you should be able to use 'hadoop fs -ls gs://CONFIGBUCKET/dir/file' in the hadoop shell. Please check [this](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Accessing-Google-Cloud-Storage-via-HDP/ta-p/248754) tutorial and also be sure that you are properly [configured access to Google Cloud Storage](https://docs.cloudera.com/HDPDocuments/Cloudbreak/Cloudbreak-2.7.1/content/gcp-data/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to access HDFS through Hadoop CLI is to SSH on the Dataproc cluster master node and use CLI utilities there:

```sh
gcloud compute ssh ${DATAPROC_CLUSTER_NAME}-m
hdfs dfs -ls
hadoop fs -ls gs:/
```

It doesn't work in Cloud Shell because it doesn't have Hadoop CLI utilities pre-installed.